# How to delete entity related to another entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this entities:

Batch, Malt, Country - batch contains malts (@ManyToMany), malt came from some country (@ManyToOne).
Relations are as following:

Batch:

```
@JoinTable(name="batch_malt",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="batch_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="malt_id"))
private Set<Malt> malts = new HashSet<>();
```

Malt:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="country_id")
private Country country;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="malts")
private Set<Batch> batches;
```

Country:
No mappinge since it is @ManyToOne from Malt.

Country Service:

```
@Override
    public void deleteById(Long countryIdToDelete) {

        Set<Malt> malts = maltRepository.findByCountry_id(countryIdToDelete);
        if (malts != null) {
            for (Malt tempMalt : malts) {
                log.debug("Deleting country from malt number: " + tempMalt.getMaltName());
                tempMalt.setCountry(null);
            }
            maltRepository.deleteById(countryIdToDelete);
        }
    }
```

I want to delete Country (I don't want to delete Malt - null shoul be instead)

When I'm trying do delete Country I get:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKM636T1NDS3GNKJC6WG8MCG21L: PUBLIC.BATCH_MALT FOREIGN KEY(MALT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MALT(ID) (2)"; SQL statement: delete from malt where id=? [23503-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKM636T1NDS3GNKJC6WG8MCG21L: PUBLIC.BATCH_MALT FOREIGN KEY(MALT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MALT(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:
delete from malt where id=? [23503-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Naruszenie więzów integralności: "FKM636T1NDS3GNKJC6WG8MCG21L: PUBLIC.BATCH_MALT FOREIGN KEY(MALT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MALT(ID) (2)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKM636T1NDS3GNKJC6WG8MCG21L: PUBLIC.BATCH_MALT FOREIGN KEY(MALT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MALT(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:
delete from malt where id=? [23503-197]
```

What should I change to be able to delete Country?

Link to whole repo: https://github.com/fangirsan/maruszka-new

Comment: You should use the countryRepository to delete the country, instead of using the maltRepository.

Comment: I'm using countryRepository (country service code block in post), I'm not using maltRepository

Comment: Read your code: `maltRepository.deleteById(countryIdToDelete);`: so you are using maltRepository to delete a country.

Comment: Ok, I get this :) But now I'm getting this: `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.maruszka.model.Country entity with id 2 exists!`